# How to optimize Mysql window function?

Tags: mysql, window-functions

I am using the window function in Mysql to compute the number of transactions the user had within the previous seven days for every transaction of a user.

to find the number of the transaction by each user in the past 7 days. I have the following query:

```
select transaction_id, user_id, date,
count(transaction_amount) over( partition by user_id order by date ASC RANGE BETWEEN  INTERVAL 7 DAY PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as total_count
from transaction;
```

The results should be like this:
[image]

My query works fine. I just wonder is there any way to optimize the query? I think indexing would not help in my case, as the window function should scan each row. I would appreciate the answers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ' number of the transaction by each user in the past 7 days' - windows functions are not the first approach that comes to mind what's wrong with a simple group by on user id where date in range? Please add sample data and desired output as text to the question.

Comment: I am so sorry, I see that I have not made it enough clear. I edited the question. Basically, I need to find the number of transactions the user had within the previous seven days for every transaction of a user.

Comment: Columns 1 and 4 are at odds with each other -- How can you have a transction_id, when there are 0 transactions?  Or list only 1 id when there are 2 ids?

Comment: The problem is about calculating the number of transactions in the past 7 days for every transaction. It is optional that the current transaction is included or not. Anyway, I solved the problem but I wonder is there any way to optimize it. Maybe you have an idea?